# What is the benefit of wrapping angular controller/service/factory declarations in an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, closures

I've seen a few developers tout 'best practices' when wrapping angular components in anonymous functions. For example:

```
(function(){
     angular.controller('MyCtrl', [function(){
         // ... controller logic
     }]);
})()
```

What is the benefit of wrapping angularjs components in anonymous functions, if at all any?

Comment: I think it's the IIFE part that is more important, not that the function is a closure.

Answer (score 0):

This is an immediately invoked function.

```
(function(){

})()
```

The above will declare an anonymous function that will be called immediately.

Comment: In theory every function is a closure in JS...

Comment: Could you please explain this more? Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: A closure is a function that has a reference to the environment it was created in to resolve free variables. That's what all functions in JS do (in theory, browser may optimize). Besides, whether the function is a closure or not is irrelevant. Pointing to IIFE is correct though.

Comment: Ok, I got it and I re-edited my answer. Thank you !